# How to disable middle click + drag right?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kde, kde-plasma-5, mouse-gestures

I'm using KDE Plasma on Ubuntu 18.04 and I have a very annoying shortcut: Middle click + Drag right -> Open a new instance of Konsole. It's annoying because it gets triggered regardless of the application I'm using. I can't use middle click + drag to rotate around my scene in Blender for example. How can I disable it?

P.S: It might be the case that I set this shortcut by myself in the past. I just don't remember it and looking for a way to disable it.

```
❯ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
❯ plasmashell --version
plasmashell 5.12.9
❯ kf5-config --version
Qt: 5.9.5
KDE Frameworks: 5.44.0
kf5-config: 1.0
```

**Update:** I created a new user and it didn't have the shortcut. That actually proves that I've messed something up in my main user. I tried to look at all the settings, submenus, all the tabs of submenus but couldn't find anything relevant. Is there a program where I can tweak the settings more?

Comment: Did you try `Right-click on the desktop`-->`Configure Desktop`-->`Mouse Actions`-->`Middle Button`  Is should be written `paste`, then to modify the associated command or to use the `-` symbol on its right to delete the action. Then Apply. Let me know.

Comment: @Hastur There was no middle button option. I might have deleted it before. I added it manually and set it to "paste". Nothing has changed. "Middle click + drag right" still opens up Konsole.

Comment: Did you add any action to "paste"?

Comment: @Hastur No, there are only 2 actions. Vertical-Scroll and Right-Button are bounded to Switch Desktop and Standard Menu respectively.

Comment: Well, then give it a try. Add an action for `Middle Button`, and `paste` and bound it to something. See if it will overwrite your previous _forgotten_ operation `:-)`. Good Luck. Ps> For the future do a file text with the non standard settings you modify on your computer. Memory is a limited resource on humans too.

Comment: @Hastur I already tried it :) *"I added it manually and set it to "paste". Nothing has changed."*. I'll definitely do, thanks!

Comment: You see... _"Memory is a limited resource on humans too"_ I forgot what I read few hours before `:)`. BTW try to add a new user and control if that behaviour is the same for the new user too. You will have some info more...

Comment: @Hastur Yes, it worked! The annoying shortcut is gone. I looked through the default settings of the new user but couldn't find anything notable. And there is literally no setting about clicking and dragging to a *specific* direction I wonder how did I even changed it...

Comment: Is it gone even from your usual user? Probably it loaded the settings from some other points, then you have overwritten them trying to associate a command to that action (it deleted the old setting). Then restarting (or switching the user) you reloaded the actual setting... Let me know and I will post as answer.

Comment: @Hastur No, it's still there. Sorry for making you think that it's the case.

Comment: No problem. There is a fact that is better to underline. For what I understand you have Ubuntu (not Kubuntu) and plasma on it... If this is correct you should see even for the Ubuntu settings relative to the mouse desktop actions and in general inside user settings details (you can compare one by one with the second user). BTW give it a look in `~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc` (maybe with `grep paste `), in `~/.kde`, in `.config`and (again) in the analog for ubuntu.

Comment: @Hastur I was writing a detailed comment and I found the related setting thanks to you! When I do `grep -e '[Mm]iddle' *rc` in `~/.config`, I saw an output that says *"... just press the middle mouse button and start drawing one of the gestures, and after you are finished, release the mouse button. If you only need to paste the selection, it still works, just click the middle mouse button. (You can change the mouse button to use in the global settings).\n\nRight now, there are the following gestures available:\nmove right and back left - Forward (Alt+Right)..."* and I screamed "yes!" :D

Comment: Because this sentence made me remember a setting that I made earlier (like 2 years ago). The related setting was in `System Settings -> Workspace -> Shortcuts -> Custom Shortcuts`. A custom shortcut called "test" which is triggered by middle click + drag right and is assigned to action "Konsole" was created by me. When I disable it, everything turns back to normal. Feel free to write an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks for taking your time to help. If you hadn't pointed me in the right direction I really wouldn't have found it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A first note is that the OP uses plasma under Ubuntu and not under Kubuntu.
A second is that there was a manual modification in a file, the memory of which in detail was lost over time.

In general it should be possible to associate a command to the middle button paste action of the desktop via

> `Right-click` on the desktop-->`Configure Desktop`-->`Mouse Actions`-->`Middle Button`.  Is should be written `paste` and then it should be possible to modify the associated command.

In the specific OP cases it was not enough. Then the suggestion to investigate *by hands* the configuration files.

Before under `~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc` (maybe with `grep paste nomefile`), under the `~/.kde` directory and under `.config`.

Then (again) in the analogue files for Ubuntu.
The OP solved the problem with `grep -e '[Mm]iddle' *rc in ~/.config`: the output helped to remember a modification made two year earlier in
`System Settings` -> `Workspace` -> `Shortcuts` -> `Custom Shortcuts`.

> A custom shortcut called "test" which is triggered by middle click + drag right and is assigned to action "Konsole" was created. Once disabled everything turned  back to normal.